# Drop the entire row in the dataframe based on column 'Amount.Requested' having missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

Consider if I have a column `Amount.Requested` and it has some missing values, so now based on those missing values from `Amount.Requested` I want to drop the entire row, because if the column `Amount.Requested` has missing values then there is no point in keeping the data of that client for my sample code.

Comment: When you say missing values, are those Nulls or spaces? Also, is Amount.Requested an integer or floay or string? Please provide more information on how the data sample looks and what is the expected output that you like to see.

Comment: when i use ->raw_data.value_counts(['Amount.Requested']) it gives 'int', but when i use ->raw_data.dtypes it returns 'Object', thats another confusion

Comment: Does this help ? ````df = df.loc[df['Amount.Requested'] > 0]````

Comment: when i checked the original csv file it had ' . ' in missing numbes places. so what is actually happening here?, if i coerce errors it will convert those ' . ' to null values, so now i have to remove null values from my column and the rows associated with those null values.

Comment: If you have nulls, then to remove rows with nulls alone try ````df = df.loc[~df['Amount.Requested'].isna()]````

Comment: thanks it worked :), but using '>0' removed missing values, but how? i mean are NaN's considered 0's?? cause i converted 'Amount.Requested' to numeric

Comment: bot of them worked well, but using '>0' removed missing values, but how? i mean are NaN's considered 0's?? cause i converted 'Amount.Requested' to numeric, Sorry i am fairly new to coding.

Comment: NaN assumes Floating point. Since your question is addressed, provided solution below,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nulls, then to remove rows with nulls alone try

```
df = df.loc[~df['Amount.Requested'].isna()] 

or

df = df.loc[df['Amount.Requested'] > 0]
```